# ROS topic sync with different frame rates

Tags: ros

Say I have multiple ROS topics to subscribe. Normally I can use message_filters::sync_policies with exactTime or approximateTime. But due to the property

> Messages are used only once. Two sets cannot share the same message. Some messages can be dropped.

which means it will only run the binded callback function when all the topics are linked into a set.

In some cases, one of the incoming topics, let's say **topic A** has half the rate than the others, let's say **B and C**, and I don't want to drop any of the B or C topics to yield to A, is there an off-the-shelf method or algorithm?

For example, I could duplicate or interpolate the A messages. Or I could produce some "fake" A messages (which does not take much resources) so I could easily enter the callback function.

If there is no such package, I think I might try to write one which might contribute to some special cases. If I make this by my own, I must pay a lot of time to ensure it works. What do you think?

Answer (score 0):

Using [message_filters::Cache](http://docs.ros.org/api/message_filters/html/c++/classmessage__filters_1_1Cache.html) might be a manual workaround for you.

- Cache your `topic A` with a queue of at least 2, if everything was smooth, but I would go always a bit higher at least.
- In your (synchronized) topics `topic B/C` callback, you can retrieve the latest message from the `topic A` cache with `getLatestTime()`.

Therefore, you'll have two (cached `topic A` and synced `topic B/C`) subscribers in your code.

Comment: Thanks. That sounds like a good idea. Currently what I do is just put every subscribed (fast) msgs into a vector and calculate the difference of timestamp in the (slow) msgs callback function and do linear interpolation. I will try the cache one and test it!